# find and remove files with space using find command on Linux

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, ubuntu

I'm trying to remove all `thumbs.db` files in a Windows partition using **find** command in Ubuntu:

```
find . -iname "*.db"|while read junk;do rm -rfv $junk;done
```

But it's not working for me and nothing happens! I think I found the problem, the white spaces in directory names!

I did this trick to remove my junk files before on previous version of Ubuntu but now on latest version of Ubuntu I can't.

Is there any bug in my command?

Comment: does `find . -iname "*.db"` return anything?

Comment: This question really belongs on http://superuser.com/

Comment: @mat: yes it returns path of founded Thumbs.db files. But I think I found the problem, the white spaces in directory names!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
find . -iname 'thumbs.db' -exec rm -rfv {} +
```

This way, it still works even if your directories contain whitespace in their names.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I think my problem also was white space in directories names.

Comment: In Windows Thumbs.db is with a capital T: `find . -iname 'Thumbs.db' -exec rm -rfv {} +` also useful: `find . -iname 'desktop.ini' -exec rm -rfv {} +`

Answer (score 35):

just to throw this out there

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -delete
```

Comment: One day i will win this contest of highest up-voted answer ;)

Comment: This is nice for directories with spaces in them.

`find . -type d \( -name bin -o -name target \) -delete`

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure why you're using `while`.

```
find . -iname 'thumbs.db' -exec rm -rfv {} \;
```

...should suffice (and only delete the files you want to, not any BDB files that may be laying around).

Answer (score 1):

The code looks good and works on arch and debian. Maybe there are no files matching "*.db"?

As a sidenote: I might not be a good idea to delete all files with the suffix ".db", because you can accidently delete other files than "Thumbs.db"

Answer (score 0):

First check if the first part of your command, that is:

> find . -iname "*.db"

is returning anything.

If it does then you can use `xargs` as follows to accomplish your task:

> find . -iname "*.db" | xargs rm -rfv

UPDATE: From comments, this is unsafe, specially if there are spaces in directory/file names. You will need to use `-print0` / `xargs -0` to make it safe.

Comment: that's dangerous if files or directories have spaces in them. you'll need the `-print0`/`xargs -0` combination to make it safe (or use the `-exec` method)

Comment: @Mat: For mine and other learning sake can you please write here what is unsafe about it? Thanks.

Comment: Try this in an empty directory: `mkdir -p "a/b c" ; touch b ; touch c ; find . -iname 'b*' | xargs -n 1 echo`. You'll see `c` printed out in its own line. If you replace `echo` with an `rm` variant, it will remove the file called `c` when you asked for `-iname 'b*'`.

Comment: @Mat: Thanks a lot for this note, I think this is an important notice about this command to prevent deleting wrong files.