# Linux Bash, remove a file seperated by a space

Tags: linux, shell, find

I want to delete different several files with the linux shell.

```
find . -name ".zip" | xargs rm
```

The command works fine, but now I came across files which have names like this: "Revenue Backup2018.zip"

The command seems to split up the files into two files and can not find them

```
rm: cannot remove './Revenue': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'backup2018.zip': No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to ignore the whitespaces?

Thank you :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find and remove files with space using find command on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242026/find-and-remove-files-with-space-using-find-command-on-linux), [Make xargs handle filenames that contain spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16758525/608639), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `xargs` use find's `-delete` instead, ie:

```
find . name .zip -delete
```

Or tell find to output with null seperators instead so that xargs is not confused by the spaces, ie:

```
find . name .zip -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```